# How to use encoding while save the XML from DB to folder

Tags: xquery, marklogic

how to use encoding while download the xml from Marklogic DB to physical path?

```
Sample Query:

xdmp:save("C:\test\sample.xml", doc(uri))
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the [documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:save)? There's an actual example there:

```
xdmp:save("C:\test\sample.xml", doc(uri),
    <options xmlns="xdmp:save">
      <output-encoding>utf-8</output-encoding>
    </options>)
```

Comment: Can you provide an actual example document?

Comment: ANSI is also known as Windows-1252, try that. MarkLogic should support most common encodings..